# How does Rails instantiate objects retrieved from the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails, `ActiveRecord::Base.new` is used for instantiating new records that aren't yet saved to the database:

```
new_user = User.new(name: "Bob")
new_user.new_record? # => true
```

So how does Rails instantiate records that are retrieved from the database? Does it use the same new method and then change values like `@new_record` after the fact? Or does it use some sort of special instantiation method for records retrieved from the database?

Comment: This is a really broad question. Either you Google some appropriate guide or you dive into the source code. Not very appropriate for SO, imo.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I want to do something similar in my own application. So I guess a different way of phrasing this would be "How do I create a second, private initializer in Ruby?" 

Unfortunately though, at the time I asked this question I didn't know I was really looking for a second initializer, I just knew that I had a problem that Rails had already solved somehow and I wanted to know how. And apparently the answer is "They use `allocate` with a second initializer method."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **new_record?** method can be found in **active_record/persistence.rb** in the ActiveRecord framework and it looks like this:

```
def new_record?
  @new_record
end
```

Then if you look at **active_record/core.rb** in the constructor you will see this:

```
def initialize(attributes = nil, options = {})
  @attributes = self.class.initialize_attributes(self.class.column_defaults.deep_dup)
  @columns_hash = self.class.column_types.dup

  init_internals # here

  ensure_proper_type

  populate_with_current_scope_attributes

  assign_attributes(attributes, options) if attributes

  yield self if block_given?
  run_callbacks :initialize if _initialize_callbacks.any?
end
```

And if we dig a little bit deeper in the code:

```
def init_internals
  pk = self.class.primary_key

  @attributes[pk] = nil unless @attributes.key?(pk)

  @aggregation_cache       = {}
  @association_cache       = {}
  @attributes_cache        = {}
  @previously_changed      = {}
  @changed_attributes      = {}
  @readonly                = false
  @destroyed               = false
  @marked_for_destruction  = false
  @new_record              = true # here
  @mass_assignment_options = nil
end
```

As you can see, the **@new_record is initialized to true by default**.

However there is some case where the @new_record attribute is set to true like when you clone a record:

```
user = User.first
new_user = user.clone
```

This will call the **initialize_dup** method that looks like:

```
def initialize_dup(other) # :nodoc:
  # Code removed

  @new_record  = true

  # Code removed
  super
end
```

Or of course when ActiveRecord pulls records from database. I am not sure about this part, but I think that this method is called:

```
def init_with(coder)
  @attributes = self.class.initialize_attributes(coder['attributes'])
  @columns_hash = self.class.column_types.merge(coder['column_types'] || {})

  init_internals

  @new_record = false

  run_callbacks :find
  run_callbacks :initialize

  self
end
```

Which could be done like this:

```
post = Post.allocate
post.init_with('attributes' => { 'title' => 'hello world' })
```

In the first statement, it allocates memory space on the heap without calling the constructor like new would do. Then it calls the special constructor **init_with**.

Comment: Ah, okay so it uses a different initialize method. That makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's done with `instantiate` method, which uses low-level `allocate` method instead of `new`

You can find this method [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L42-L56).